# Spring mvc classpath

Tags: spring-mvc, internationalization, classpath

in my spring mvc web-app i save message_en.properties file under

```
|-src/main/java
+---src
|   +---main
|   |   +---java
|   |   +---resources
|   |   |   +---i18n
            |   message_en.properties
            |   message_fr.properties
```

Bean declaration :

```
@Bean
public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource validationMessageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource bms = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    bms.setBasename("classpath*:i18n/message");
    bms.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    return bms;
}

@Bean
public CookieLocaleResolver localeResolver() {
    CookieLocaleResolver localeResolver = new CookieLocaleResolver();
    localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
    localeResolver.setCookieName("my-locale-cookie");
    localeResolver.setCookieMaxAge(3600);
    return localeResolver;
}

@Bean
public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeInterceptor() {
    LocaleChangeInterceptor interceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
    interceptor.setParamName("lang");
    return interceptor;
}

@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(localeInterceptor());
}
```

in the console i still getting the message  :

```
DEBUG org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource - No properties file found for [classpath*:i18n/message] - neither plain properties nor XML
16:13:24.432 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource - No properties file found for [classpath*:i18n/message_fr] - neither plain properties nor XML
16:13:24.432 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource - No properties file found for [classpath*:i18n/message_fr_FR] - neither plain properties nor XML
16:13:24.432 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource - No properties file found for [classpath*:i18n/message_en] - neither plain properties nor XML
```

Please how to set the attribute Basename in the validationMessageSource Bean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues in above code

a. First Issue is

```
@Bean
public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource validationMessageSource()
```

signature should be like below (either one)

```
@Bean(name = "messageSource") <--- Name of the Bean should be messageSource
    public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource validationMessageSource() {
}
```

or it should be like below, with method name as messageSource instead of putting Bean name as "messageSource" like above

```
@Bean
    public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
}
```

b. Second Issue is

```
bms.setBasename("classpath*:i18n/message");
```

should be `bms.setBasename("classpath:i18n/message");` <--- No * required in classpath